# Python regex split on plus or minus and keep character

Tags: python, regex

I have a set of data like this:

```
data_list = ['0+.25+4.06+5.12', '0+0-.033+933.00+9+48.002']
```

The only delimiters are the plus and minus signs. I want to keep the plus or minus signs but still split on them. The first 0 in front of the element also is not needed.

Here's what I have so far:

```py
import re
    
data_list = ['0+.25+4.06+5.12', '0+0-.033+933.00+9+48.002']
data_string = ""
for item in data_list:
    data_string += item[1:]
data_string = re.split(', |\+|-', data_string)
new_data_list = []
for item in data_string:
    if item:
        new_data_list.append(item)

print(new_data_list)
```

This gives me close to the right output:

```
['.25', '4.06', '5.12', '0', '.033', '933.00', '9', '48.002']
```

but now I cannot determine which one is positive or negative.

I would like output to be like this:

```
['.25', '4.06', '5.12', '0', '-.033', '933.00', '9', '48.002']
```

where I can see that `.033` is a negative number.

Comment: Don't use `re.split()`, use `re.findall()` with a regular expression that matches the number with an optional plus or minus prefix.

Comment: Does it mean the first `0+` must be removed?

Comment: Why do you have `, ` in the regular expression? That doesn't seem to be a delimiter in any of your strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done in a single `findall` without any loop:

```py
import re
data_list = ['0+.25+4.06+5.12', '0+0-.033+933.00+9+48.002']

print (re.findall(r'-?(?!0+[ +])\d*\.?\d+', ' '.join(data_list)))
```

**Output:**

```
['.25', '4.06', '5.12', '0', '-.033', '933.00', '9', '48.002']
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gBW3V3/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `-?`: Match optional `-`
- `(?!0+[ +])`: Negative lookahead to fail the match if we have just `0`s in input
- `\d*\.?\d+`: Match an integer ot floating point number

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```py
import re
 
data_list = ['0+.25+4.06+5.12', '0+0-.033+933.00+9+48.002']
new_data_list = []
for item in data_list:
    new_data_list.extend(re.split(r'\+|(?=-)', item[2:]))
 
print(new_data_list)
# => ['.25', '4.06', '5.12', '0', '-.033', '933.00', '9', '48.002']
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/aY5GAn).

Note:

- `item[2:]` - truncates the first two chars (if you need more precision, replace `item[2:]` with `re.sub(r'^0\+', '', item)`)
- `\+|(?=-)` matches a `+` or a location that is immediately followed with a `-` char.

Answer (score 0):

You could try with this list comprehension:

```
[el for el in re.findall('[+-]\d*\.?\d+', ''.join(data_list))]
```

Regex explanation:

- `[+-]`: beginning symbol
- `\d*`: optional numbers
- `\.?`: optional dot
- `\d+`: decimal numbers